# Query Parse User Data

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, back4app

I have many columns in the "User" class in parse/back{4}app. I'm trying to get data from a specific column by using this code

```
ParseQuery query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        query.getInBackground(String.valueOf(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(ParseUser parseObject, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // The query was successful.
                    t = (ParseObject) parseObject.get("Gender");
                    gender.setText(t.toString());
                } else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                }
            }
        }));
```

As you can see, I made a ParseObject (which is variable "t") and tried to put the data from the dashboard in it, then made it into a string to be put into an editText (gender). But nothing is being shown in the editText after I run the application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
Just use this simple code to get what you want from the "User" Class

Note: "test" is a String,
      "gender" is EditText

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        test = user.get("Gender").toString();
        gender.setText(test);
```